# Can I use an abstract base class as a Unity Editor element?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm trying to create a component for a Unity `GameObject`, let's call it `MediaController`. I want it to be able to manage timing (play/pause/etc) for different media (audio/video). I created an abstract class `PlayableMedia` with basic properties/fields/methods and created 2 classes, `PlayableVideo` and `PlayableAudio`, that inherit and implement according to our needs.

The intent was to have a singular list of `PlayableMedia` that could be audio/video agnostic, allowing an easy (i.e.) `media.Play()` call regardless of type at specific app times... but my field `public List<PlayableMedia> MediaList;` is not appearing in the editor and there is no error.

So ultimately my question is as the title states: **is it possible to use the `PlayableMedia` class as the type of a field?**

I'm suspecting "no" based on my experiences with this, but I've found links that say "yes" or "yes, sort of" that seem to point [to custom editors/inspectors/drawers](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/property-drawers-custom-inspectors), but I have 0 experience with those and haven't been able to get it implemented (see below).

```
[System.Serializable]
public class RegisteredMedia
{
    public float StartTime;
    public PlayableMedia Media;
}

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(RegisteredMedia))]
class RegisteredMediaDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), new GUIContent("Playable Media"));

        var indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;

        Rect rectStartTime = new Rect(position.x, position.y, 30, position.height);
        Rect rectMedia = new Rect(position.x + 35, position.y, 50, position.height);

        EditorGUI.PropertyField(rectStartTime, property.FindPropertyRelative("StartTime"), GUIContent.none);
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(rectMedia, property.FindPropertyRelative("Media"), GUIContent.none);

        EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}

public class MediaController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<RegisteredMedia> MediaList = new List<RegisteredMedia>();

    \\[...] rest of implementation
}
```

Can anyone help me out? Either confirm that it isn't possible, or help me with an implementation if it is?

Also, if it can be done with custom editors/inspectors/drawers, can someone help me get a single item in the `List<RegisteredMedia>` to display as `Start Time ____  Playable Media [=====]` (where `PlayableMedia` will be a `GameObject` with the proper component attached)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful of your use of the word "property". [In C# it means something very specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

> is it possible to use the PlayableMedia class as the type of a property?

I think you are asking the wrong question here. Rather than coming up with a new implementation, consider why your current implementation might not be working?

Firstly, I'll give you the following example:

```
public abstract class Car : MonoBehaviour { }

public class Jeep : Car { }

public class Ferrari : Car { }

public class CarHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Car> Cars;
}
```

In this example, I could create a GameObject with the CarHolder component, and was able to attach both Jeep and Ferrari Objects. It is important to note that each monoBehavior class I defined sits in its own file and the file name matches the class name. This is just how Unity works.

So to answer the question I think you are asking (assuming we replace "property" with "field"), it is indeed possible to use abstract class types and have them show up in the inspector. I suspect that you need to separate your classes into separate files.

Comment: **1** You're absolutely right, I mixed up the terms, my apologies; I was confusing my implementations, I'm doing props elsewhere lol. **2** Whelp, I found my problem thanks to you, and I really hate myself right now. Hours of trying to solve this, looking into custom editors/inspectors/drawers to (as you pointed out) solve an issue I didn't really have... and my abstract `PlayableMedia` class just needed `: MonoBehaviour`. **3** Yeah, they're all in separate files, I just amalgamated the code here for brevity :).

Comment: Don't be frustrated about those kind of errors. Its more important to realize why you made the error in the first place, and then why you couldn't identify it. From now on you should be able to realize that if things don't show up as components its probably because they aren't monobehaviors. I've made this mistake dozens of times but I'm now very quick to diagnose the problem. 

Every mistake that you make but then rationalize will make you a better programmer.

Comment: Oh, I know, but thanks for the support! I'm a pretty experienced programmer, just inexperienced with Unity programming. I'm frustrated because I've made custom components several times and always remembered the `MonoBehaviour` before, so I'm just kicking myself now haha. Rest assured, this will be my first "check" next time it's not working haha. As for *why* I forgot it this time, I'm getting pulled onto several projects at the same time, I probably just slipped up/got sloppy. But again, thanks for your help, it's much appreciated! :D

Comment: What about where the class doesn't inherit from `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject`? I have an abstract class `Module`, each inherited class has different parameters (including some that require modules of their own) and what I'm hoping to be able to do is show a dropdown (determined by enum) that shows all 'types' of Modules and to display the appropriate property drawer for them.

Comment: I don't think that is possible with inheriting from scriptable object or Monobehavior. You could make your abstract class inherit from one f those. Alternatively, you could write a class that holds the references you want, as well as a "Module", and that class could pass its references to Module when they are changed. Pretty janky though.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible natively since 2019.3 release via `[SerializeReference]` attribute https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeReference.html

e.g.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public abstract class AbstractExample {
    public int foo;
}

// [Serializable] not needed here
public class ConcreteExample : AbstractExample {
}

public class Consumer : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeReference]
    public List<AbstractExample> examples = new() { new ConcreteExample() };

    // both the list and the concrete instance visible in the editor
    // and editable without any additional editor extensions

    // note that you can't effectively add new items to the list via editor
    // since that way you create a faulty abstract-ish instances instead
    // (no actual way for the editor to know what subtype do you want)

    // if you're OK with having the base class being not explicitly abstract
    // and can provide a sensible constructor for it, just drop the abstract
    // you'll still have full polymorphism support etc. with SerializeReference
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example ?

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque example added